# IIS sites configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have configured 2 sites in my local.

1 - Default Web Site (Application pool - DefaultAppPool) port 80*

2 - My web site (Application pool - his own application pool), my binding is site.test.local port 80, I have in my hosts file 127.0.0.1 site.test.local

If the both are running I don't have problems, "My web site" is running correctly, but if I disable Default Web Site site, the browser raise this error "503 Service Unavaialble. No server is available to handle this request"

How do I prevent that having that 503 error?

Comment: This question would be better for Server Fault since it isn't directly about programming.

Comment: If may be helpful to post your configuration, open C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config and copy the `<sites>` node under  `<system.applicationHost>`, then we could see what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your "My web site" in the same level path of the "Default Web Site", using another App_Pool and other port.

Right click on Sites -> Add Site

Comment: Actually the both are in the same level, and I need port 80 as well, if Default Web Site is disabled, I shouldn't have problems with the port (I guess)

Comment: No, you don't have problems to set the same port, but you can't start all sites at the same time.

Well, i told that you put the both sites in the same lavel, under Site path, pointing to differents app_pool and when you are stopping the Default Site, the other one stops too.

Did you try stop the Default web site and after this restart IIS and test you own site? Just to verify ;)